# How do I check if pm-powersave is on?

Tags: 16.04, power-management

How do I check if `pm-powersave` is on in Ubuntu 16.04?

Nothing shows up when I google this.

Comment: This page might help explain a little more:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower

Comment: I've already looked at this, it doesn't say how to check if pm-powersave is on or not.